# ForEach loop, trying to calculate average

Tags: powershell

My objective is to write a script that examines log files for the duration of an event, calculates the duration based on log entries (start/finish), and then calculates the average of those durations over the last 24 hours and determines whether it is greater than a certain value (let's use 2 hours for an example).  So far, I have the first two portions completed, it is examining the logs properly and calculating the duration for each applicable log.  I just don't know where to begin with the last step, the averaging of the durations from all of the logs.  Below is my code thus far.

```
$imagesuccess = Get-ChildItem '\\server\osd_logs\success' -Directory | 
    Where-Object {
        ($_.Name -like "P0*") -or (($_.Name -like "MININT*") -and
        (Test-Path "$($_.FullName)\SCCM_C\Logs\SMSTSLog\Get-PSPName.log")) -and
        ($_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-24))
    }

$sccmlogpaths = "\\s0319p60\osd_logs\success\$($imagesuccess)\SCCM_C\Logs\SMSTSLog\smsts.log"

foreach ($sccmlogpath in $sccmlogpaths) {
    $imagestartline = Select-String -Pattern "<![LOG[New time:" -Path $sccmlogpath -SimpleMatch
    $imagestarttime = $imagestartline.ToString().Substring(75, 8)

    $imagefinishline = Select-String -Pattern "<![LOG[    Directory: M:\$($imagesuccess)" -Path $sccmlogpath -SimpleMatch
    $imagefinishtime = $imagefinishline.ToString().Substring(71, 8)

    $imageduration = New-TimeSpan $imagestarttime $imagefinishtime
    $imagedurationstring = $imageduration.ToString()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Roughly you'd do this:

```
$durations = foreach ($sccmlogpath in $sccmlogpaths) {
    # [snip]

    $imageduration = New-TimeSpan $imagestarttime $imagefinishtime

    $imageduration  # the 'output' of the foreach () {}
}


# $durations is now an array of timespans

$measurements = $durations | Measure-Object -Average -Property TotalHours
$averageHours = $measurements.Average

if (2.5 -lt $averageHours) {
    # code here
}
```

This does sum(n)/count(n) averaging.

NB. if you are querying the last -24 hours, New-TimeSpan won't work nicely if any of the durations cross midnight; it will see 23:01 -> 00:01 as -23 hours.

Comment: @RyanBemrose yes! Total mistake, thank you for picking up on it. (I've edited to correct that).

Comment: Awesome approach!  I like the use of an array, and I was just drawing a blank on where to start.  I love this method.  One question, I think that I may run into some issues with the format my durations are using.  Right now they are HH:MM:SS, and I would like to try and keep it that way.  Will that play well with the averaging method?

Comment: @LilithGoddess The array contains PowerShell `[TimeSpan]` objects which are independent of what string format you use.

Comment: Thanks @RyanBemrose - I am just curious because I am running into the error "The Property TotalSeconds cannot be found in the input for any objects".  Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: @LilithGoddess Your array isn't getting set to an array of `$imageduration`.  Did you update your code after the answer was edited?  It won't work with an array of strings.

Comment: @LilithGoddess I've edited a change for that into my answer; you can average the TotalHours property directly instead of going through TotalSeconds, and work with the average instead of making a new-timespan at the end. (I used Seconds and left it as a timespan because I wasn't sure what kind of timescales you are working with)

Comment: @RyanBemrose thank you  :)  I did not see the edit.  Sorry.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler thank you so much!  This helped me a ton.  I have things cleaned up now and working as expected.  :)